# Getting error in template: Impossible to access an attribute ("getUrl") on a NULL variable ("")

Tags: templating, matrix, image

This was working fine previously and not sure what triggered the error. Any idea how to resolve issue?

```
{% for block in entry.servicesItems.type('images') %}
    <div class="col">

        {# grab the first image #}
        {% set image = block.image.first() %}

        {# link to the full sized version #}
            <a href="{{ image.getUrl }}">
        {# generated the transformed thumbnail version #}
            <img src="{{ image.getUrl('servicesImageCrop')}}" alt="{{ block.alt }}" width="{{ image.getWidth('servicesImageCrop') }}" height="{{ image.getHeight('servicesImageCrop') }}">
            <div id="lightbox-title">
                <h2>{{ block.imageTitle }}</h2>
                <p>{{ block.imageContent }}</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Figured it out, it was actually caused by an empty matrix block in an entry. Any idea how to prevent this from page error if user accidentally does this?

Comment: You can check if it is defined first using `{% if block.image.first() %}...{% endif %}` or `{% if image %}...{% endif %}`.

Comment: Can you add that as an official answer, @frshjb373?

Comment: If you found an answer to your question, you can post it :) Answering own questions is not discouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just test if image is defined first using:

```
{% set image = block.image.first() %}
{% if image %}
    <a href="{{ image.getUrl() }}">...</a>
{% endif %}
```